# Mysterious white space codes for a non ASCII character

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I am transcribing a paper to LaTeX. To do so, I converted the `docx` file to a `txt` file with the MacOs word processor *pages*. Some of the characters were mapped into their non-ASCII form, e.g., ∑, ∂, etc... So I changed one by one into the proper LaTeX equivalent. However, a blank space in the converted `txt` file was compiling into a weird character with LaTeX.

Here is (a summary of) my LaTeX input.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{Document}
Blah, Blah, Blah
.
.
.

[...] is defined as follows: $d_{i,j} = w_{i,j}^{mut} - w_{i,j}^{wt}$ [...]
                            ^
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

After `pdflatex myfile.tex` I got this output:

[image: Output]

As you can see, there's a mysterious white space after the colon coded for two accented letter As and another letter I. Why is that? How can I predict this kind of errors?

Comment: There are quite a number of spaces in unicode (see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm). Add \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}, then you will (get either a space or an error message.

Comment: did you retype that rather than copy it from your document, as it has a normal space after the colon, I would have expected to see a non-ascii character there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

You have a control character (apparently U+2028 which is LINE SEPARATOR) after the colon, which takes three bytes in UTF-8 but are using the default single byte input encoding in latex, so each byte is being printed as a separate character as shown above which is made from

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \begin{document}

    U+2008 Punctation space : x

    U+2028 Line separator :     x

    \end{document}
```

If you add

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

then you get a more understandable behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

U+2008 Punctation space : x

U+2028 Line separator :     x

\end{document}
```

produces terminal output:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char   (U+2008)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

..

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char  (U+2028)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The file I transcribed presented just a few of those line separators which were converted from `docx` to `txt`. Do you happen to know why these unicode line separators were added by the word processor (the original file was processed in `word')? Are they used to `harmonize' the document?

Comment: @rodgdor there is no point in thinking about why Word does anything, that way lies despair. Actually I know nothing about Word other than it isn't emacs.

Comment: Fair enough :-)